# Kubernetes Networkpolicy not working as expected

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy, kubernetes-networking

I have a k8s cluster that spreads worker nodes in 6 AZs and hence, egress traffic gets routed through 6 nat gateways. My requirement is that all egress traffic for app 'xyz' should be routed through only AZ- A's nat gateway. So as a solution I created an nginx proxy instance in the same namespace, putting an affinity rule to bind it to only AZ - A and thought of routing egress traffic from `xyz` pod to this proxy instance using network policy. But seems like the network policy is blocking the whole egress traffic. Below is the code for egress NW policy which seems fine.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: xyz-app-egress
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xyz
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress: 
  - {}
  egress:
    - to:
      - podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app: proxy
```

I am testing using `curl ifconfig.co` on the xyz pod after applying the NW policy. And it gives below error and timeouts sometime:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ifconfig.co
```

I think I am missing something here. Could anybody please provide me any insights on this? or a better solution to this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a egress rule as indicated [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-allow-all-egress-traffic) instead of an ingress rule.

```
  egress:
   - {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have blocked all DNS queries, so as workaround please [try this approach](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/network-policy#step_3_restrict_outgoing_traffic_from_the_pods) as DNS traffic occurs on port 53 using TCP and UDP protocols:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: foo-allow-to-hello
spec:
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xyz
  ingress: 
  - {}
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: proxy
  - ports:
    - port: 53
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP
```